# systemd service won't start at boot

Tags: systemd, docker

I am creating a systemd service to auto start a docker container. It runs perfectly during the current session with `systemctl start`, but it fails to auto start at boot (I have it `enable`d).

The service unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=TiddlyWiki Container
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStartSec=60
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=%n
Environment="TW_PORT=8080"
Environment="TW_DOCKERVOLUME=%n"
Environment="TW_DOCKERUID=0"
Environment="TW_DOCKERGID=0"
EnvironmentFile=/etc/tiddlywiki/%n.conf
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop %n
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm %n
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull nicolaw/tiddlywiki
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -p ${TW_PORT}:${TW_PORT} -e TW_PORT=${TW_PORT} --env-file /etc/tiddlywiki/%n.conf --user ${TW_DOCKERUID}:${TW_DOCKERGID} -v ${TW_DOCKERVOLUME}:/var/lib/tiddlywiki --name %n nicolaw/tiddlywiki
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/docker stop %n

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the log from `journalctl`

```
Dec 11 00:54:58 ub-2004-ins3 systemd[1]: tidwiki.service: Found ordering cycle on multi-user.target/stop
Dec 11 00:54:58 ub-2004-ins3 systemd[1]: tidwiki.service: Found dependency on docker.service/stop
Dec 11 00:54:58 ub-2004-ins3 systemd[1]: tidwiki.service: Found dependency on tidwiki.service/stop
Dec 11 00:54:58 ub-2004-ins3 systemd[1]: tidwiki.service: Job multi-user.target/stop deleted to break ordering cycle starting with tidwiki.service/stop
```

I guess the problem is due to `WantedBy` target in `[Install]` section. But I have no idea what target value is suitable other than `multi-user.target`.

Please help.

Comment: What type of service is this? Is is something related to docker? `WARNING: Error loading config file: .dockercfg: $HOME is not defined` This line I think is the one you need to focus on.

Comment: Yes it is docker related, but this is warning only, nor the cause pf problem. As stated, the service runs fine when started manually (this warning appears in that case too). I will edit out these parts of the log to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Sometimes you need to take warnings seriously. Can you add a log of service being started manually?

Comment: I think $HOME environment variable is not initialized when the service is triggered automatically at boot time.

Comment: Does the `systemd-analyze dot` (see manual) throw any light on the issue? The service file at https://github.com/neechbear/tiddlywiki/blob/master/tiddlywiki.service doesn't have the [Install] section at all. Is it possible that you have created a loop in the past that is no longer shown in the current file?  What is in /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants (maybe /usr/lib/systemd/systemd/multi-user.target.wants)? I usually let `docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped ...` handle the restart rather than write systemd files.

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestions. I could not figure out the a solution for systemd service. But as suggested by @icarus starting container with `--restart=unless-stopped` option works well enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
USER=root
```

to the `.service` file. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Aren't systemd services started by root by default? This doesn't seem (to me) related to the journal errors listed about "Found ordering cycle" and "Found dependency on..."